# Who owns the TemplateRef refreshing cycle in angular dart?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular2-changedetection

I am having a problem with TemplateRef refreshing cycle when used with ngTemplateOutlet.

Consider the HTML:

```
           <card [value]="item" full>

            <template #buttons let-obj="obj"> <!-- THE TEMPLATE -->
              <button (click)="myBoolean = false"
                *ngIf="myBoolean">  <!-- THIS IF -->
               SET FALSE
              </button>

              <button (click)="myBoolean = true"
                *ngIf="!myBoolean"> <!-- THIS IF --> 
               SET TRUE
              </button>
            </template>

           </card>

           <button (click)="myBoolean = !myBoolean">TOGGLE</button>
```

So a page-component has a card. 
The card has this property:

```
  @ContentChild('buttons')
  TemplateRef buttons;
```

The TemplateRef buttons is used by this code:

```
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="buttons"
     [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ 'obj': value }"></template>
```

It works well and the button is shown based on myBoolean variable of the page component. Also, when you click the buttons inside the `<template>` the cycle works and they change based on myBoolean variable.

The problem is when the myBoolean variable is changed by something outside the `<template>`. In the HTML example above, when I click the TOGGLE button, the myBoolean variable changes however the `<template>` does not refresh accordingly.

So, who owns the refresh of TemplateRef?
What can I do to make it refresh correctly?

Comment: What ChangeDetectionStrategy are you using in the component the above markup belongs to? `value` in `"{ 'obj': value }"`

Comment: OnPush @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: almost 100% of the components are using OnPush strategy

Comment: I tried ApplicationRef.tick() when setting the myBoolean outside the <template> but still the <template> did not get refresh

Comment: What about `ComponentRef.markForCheck()` You could also try to use `int` instead of `bool` and increment on each click and use `myInt % 2 == 0` to get `true`/`false`. `bool` can be a bit tricky with change detection in some (rare) situations. No idea if this applies here but worth a try I think.

Comment: I use ```markForCheck``` a lot because of the OnPush strategy, so it didn't work either. The variable myBoolean was just to make the example, the original condition is ```*ngIf="item == newChatItem.parent"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view in which the `TemplateRef` is instantiated has ownership. Because your components use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, their views will only update whenever

1. an event handler (e.g. `(event)=handleEvent`) bound in the
   component's view is triggered,
2. an input's value (e.g. `<card [input]="value">`) changes, or
3. the component has injected `ChangeDetectorRef` and invoked `changeDetector.markForCheck()`.

*Note that all three of these conditions lead to the view being marked for check; the first two implicitly, and the last explicitly.*

In your example, you're projecting a `<template>` into your `<card>` component's view. Presumably your `<card>` component is then rendering that `<template>` in its own view via `NgTemplateOutlet`. So in order for the rendered `<template>` to be updated when `myBoolean` changes, the `<card>` component has to be marked for check.

The reason the view updates properly when you click a button inside the `<template>` is due to reason (1) above. The event handler marks the view it's rendered in (the `<card>`) to be checked.

The same reason is why it *doesn't work* when you click the TOGGLE button in parent view: that only marks the parent view to be checked. So when the parent view is change detected as a result of being marked for check, the `<card>` view is skipped because none of the three conditions have been met for the `<card>` view.

So in order to have the rendered `<template>` update when the TOGGLE button is clicked, you need the handler to somehow call `markForCheck()` on the `ChangeDetectorRef` *of the view in which the `<template>` is rendered*.

The good news is this is possible, but unfortunately it's not very clean. There are a number of ways you could accomplish this, but here's an idea:

Add a method to `<card>` to abstract the details of using `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
@Component(...)
class CardComponent {
  CardComponent(this._changeDetector);

  final ChangeDetectorRef _changeDetector;

  void updateButtons() {
    _changeDetector.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

Query for the `<card>` in your page component, and call the update method when toggle is pressed:

```
@Component(...)
class PageComponent {
  @ViewChild(CardComponent)
  CardComponent card;

  void toggle() {
    myBoolean = !myBoolean;
    card.updateButtons();
  }
}
```

```
<button (click)="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
```

Hope this was helpful, cheers!

Comment: shouldn't the templateRef be owned by the page and not the card?
Because there is no way for the card to know when that template changes, only the page component.

Comment: Potentially. It's quite possible this is a corner case that simply wasn't considered. 

I'm not entirely certain of the history, but I suspect the API for querying and instantiating `TemplateRef`s predates `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, and the semantics all would have worked before with the default change detection strategy.

Comment: On the other hand, the view in which the `TemplateRef` is embedded is capable of setting local variables within that view, so it also needs ownership since it can change those variables.

Comment: almost three years later, googled about template refreshing and ended up here hahaha. I still think that templates should be refreshed their internals without having to talk to parent tho